# Absorptive and emissive power

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation

I have heard that **emissive power**
of a Black Body is defined as the energy radiated per unit area per unit time, which is a rate of energy emission,( I mean that's what power means , it's a rate).

But the definition of  **absorptive power** is given as the ratio of energy absorbed to the energy incident on the Black Body, making it dimension less.

So why are the two definitions of power not the same?

Comment: This is just semantics... where did you get that definition?

Comment: There are plenty of names, which do not really reflect their physical nature. E.g. [Optical power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_power) is an inverse length. These are sloppy names, and I would discourage you to use them. However, if you try to use proper names,  the first one is an **intensity** (energy per unit time and unit area).